# MongoDB Model One-to-Many Relationships with Embedded Documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i find on [mongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/)
this example.

```
   {   
    _id: "joe",
    name: "Joe Bookreader"  }

    {
       patron_id: "joe",
       street: "123 Fake Street",
       city: "Faketon",
       state: "MA",
       zip: "12345"
    }
    {
       patron_id: "joe",
       street: "1 Some Other Street",
       city: "Boston",
       state: "MA",
       zip: "12345"
    }
```

It also states that you can only retrieve the complete patron information with one query.

## BUT HOW ???

- db.patron.find() // no
- db.patron.aggregate // maybe

I would like such a result

```
{
   _id: "joe",
   name: "Joe Bookreader",
   addresses: [
                {
                  street: "123 Fake Street",
                  city: "Faketon",
                  state: "MA",
                  zip: "12345"
                },
                {
                  street: "1 Some Other Street",
                  city: "Boston",
                  state: "MA",
                  zip: "12345"
                }
              ]
 }
```

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. If someone is looking for a one to many relationship solution here is this one

```
 db.patron.aggregate([
            {$lookup: {from: "address",localField: "_id",foreignField: "patron_id",as: "posts"}}
        ])
```